# Crittercism i cant'see my crash on live stat

Tags: java, android, crash, crittercism

I am crashing my app now in the debug mode for testing and i am not getting any crash report for that on my dashboard.
I use this part of code

```
      Crittercism.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.crittercism_app_id));
    List<String> k = new ArrayList<String>();
    Log.i(k.get(0));
```

Any ideas that why i am not getting it will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: have you followed steps [mentioned here](https://app.crittercism.com/developers/docs-android)

Comment: yes i already do all that except <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/> i just add it but it change nothing

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by follow this page https://app.crittercism.com/developers/docs-android and crash my appli later with a click thank's for your response

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be crashing before Crittercism is fully initialized. Your app has to fully load before Crittercism will detect crashes. To test this, you might try triggering your crash with some UI event (a button click).

It's also possible that you're using another SDK which is interfering with Crittercism's exception handler. Other crash reporting SDKs are a common source. You could try logging the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler before and after the Crittercism initialization.